# Conditional COUNTIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

I have two columns:

```
A                B
0              Level 1
34             Level 2
23             Level 1
0              Level 7
5              Level 3
```

I need to find the count of rows where the ColumnA value is not `0` and the ColumnB value is either `Level 1` or `Level 2`.

The result I would like returned from the example above is `2`.

I have tried:

```
IF(A1:A6<>0,(COUNTIF(B1:B6,"=Level 1")+COUNTIF(B1:B6,"=Level 2")),"")
```

Comment: @pnuts: I have changed that to number of rows. In this case answer should be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>"&0,B:B,"Level 1")+COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>"&0,B:B,"Level 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like this solution:

`{=SUM((A1:A6<>0)*((B1:B6="Level 1")+(B1:B6="Level 2")))}`

Leave out the curly braces and enter the function by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Your formula is looking for "=Level 1", it needs to look for "Level 1" as below:

```
=IF(A1:A6<>0,(COUNTIF(B1:B6,"Level 1")+COUNTIF(B1:B6,"Level 2")),"")
```

Comment: I have tried that also . it doesnt work ..ALso "=Level 1" also works.